# Permission denied while running python script with os library?

Tags: python

My objective is to run a script which is living in a different folder. In particular, I am trying to initialize a flask api which is living in a completely different folder. Normally, I would run from the terminal my flask api as follows:

```
$ python my_app.py -config_files conf.ini
```

Then the api runs normally. However, since I am trying to run the api from another project folder I tried:

```
api = '/the/path/to/the/api/folder/project'
os.system('{} python my_app.py -config_files conf.ini'.format(api))
```

However, after trying to run my api, I am getting:

```
32256
```

and

```
[I 00:30:05.404 NotebookApp] Saving file at /noteebook.ipynb
sh: 1: /api/project/folder/path: Permission denied
sh: 1: /api/project/folder/path: Permission denied
```

Which is the correct way of running a python script living in a different folder inside another python script?

Comment: is `'/the/path/to/the/api/folder/project'` a relative or an absolute path?

Comment: @reportgunner is the full path of the project. For example, if you go to the terminal and go to that folder and do: pwd that is the output...

Comment: aha I see the problem, let me draft an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
api = '/the/path/to/the/api/folder/project'
os.system('{} python my_app.py -config_files conf.ini'.format(api))
```

That command will end up being:

```
/the/path/to/the/api/folder/project python my_app.py -config_files conf.ini
```

... which makes no sense.

Perhaps you wanted this?

```
os.system('python {}/my_app.py -config_files conf.ini'.format(api))
```

Comment: I am getting: `256`. Now I can not find the modules that the file needs. I got:  `/user/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/user/api_project_folder/'
`

Comment: That's because you're calling python with just a directory name as the first argument, instead of a script name as the argument. i.e. you're doing something like `python /foo/bar/ myscript.py` (note the space between the folder name and the script name).

Comment: So what should I do in this case?

Comment: Make sure your command is constructed properly, without a space between the directory and the script name.

Comment: still getting the same mistake... any idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the path to the script name, so the final path will be:
`python /the/path/to/the/api/folder/project/my_app.py -config_files conf.ini`

```
api = '/the/path/to/the/api/folder/project'
script_path = api + '/my_app.py'
os.system('cd {api};python {script_path} -config_files conf.ini'.format(script_path=script_path, api=api))
```

Comment: I am getting: 256. Now I can not find the modules that the file needs. I got: /user/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/user/api_project_folder/'

Comment: Perhaps you need to `cd` into the directory first as well. I've updated the answer, can you try ? Thanks !